# Supposed to be un-numbered chapters keeping the number of the previous one?

Tags: numbering, overleaf

First of all, English isn't my first language so I'm sorry for any unclear information/mistakes !

I am typing an internship report and I have a problem regarding chapter numbering. I have an un-numebered introduction (for which I used `\chapter*{Introduction}`, followed by three numbered chapters that appear normally. However, I have a conclusion and a bibliography which, although I named them using `\chapter*{Conclusion}` and `\chapter*{Bibliography}`, appear with the number 3, exactly the same as the third chapter.

[image]
[image]

To specify, I have a main file and I use `\input` to implement separate files for each part. Here's the code from the main page (I manually add the list of figures and Bibliography to my table of contents directly on it, but I also add the un-numbered chapters using for example `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}` in the separate files).

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{appendix}    
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}

\input{title}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des figures}
\input{remerciements}
\newpage
\input{introduction}
\newpage
\input{entreprise}
\newpage
\input{stage}
\newpage
\input{travaux}
\newpage
\input{conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Where does this problem come from and how can I solve it?
Thank you in advance for helping :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: We would need at least your preamble. This is not the standard behaviour.

Comment: In particular, please do mention which document class you employ.

Comment: I employ the report class.

Comment: Here is my preamble :`\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{appendix}



\addbibresource{biblio.bib}`

Comment: Without the files you input, the error is not reproducible. Could you upload at least some op the files you input, i.e. the respective preamble, some words and its last lines, in total as much as is needed to reproduce the error?